# How to map existing pages on navigation bar instead of groups

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

[image: Home page]

My home page is on your screen and as you see I have a collapsable navigation bar and navigation cards on the homepage. In my collapsable navigation bar, you can see that the menu part "Računi" has 2 subregions under it, while the 2 subregions are real working pages the element "RAČUNI" is just there to make it look good (doesn't lead to any page.

My problem is that when I click "RAČUNI" on the right navigation bar shown in the cards region it redirects me straight to the login screen of my workspace.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to create your own table which contains the whole menu.  As *cards* region is - actually - a classic report, it is you who should create query which will do what you want.

Here's an example of such a table:

[image]

- `PAGE_ID` represents page on which cards report is located; if you have two (or more) cards regions on different pages, you'd keep them all in the same table; `page_id` will distinguish them
- `CARD_ID` - primary key
- `TARGET_PAGE` - can be used in `CARD_LINK` so that Apex would know where to navigate once you click on the card

  - in your question, it is unclear what you actually want to do when you click on "Računi" card. I don't know what code you used, but - if you do as I suggest, it is completely under your control; maybe you'll have to "split" that card into two and have separate "Pregled računa" and "Ispis računa" cards. Or, maybe you'll create a new page which will then let you redirect to one of these; can't tell
- the rest of columns is, I think, self-explanatory

Example of a report query:

```
  SELECT page_id,
         card_id,
         card_title,
         card_subtitle,
         card_text,
         card_subtext,
         -- UI and other attributes
         NULL AS card_modifiers,
         --
         REPLACE (
            REPLACE (REPLACE (card_link, '<<PAR_SESSION>>', :APP_SESSION),
                     'P116_YYYYMM',
                     :P116_YYYYMM),
            'P116_ID_ORG',
            :P116_ID_ORG) card_link,
         --
         card_color,
         card_icon,
         --
         NVL (card_initials, apex_string.get_initials (card_title)) card_initials
    FROM cards
   WHERE page_id = 116
ORDER BY page_id, card_id;
```

That's it; basically, create your own query and fix `CARD_LINK` so that it does what you want.

Comment: Thank you sooo much once again for the explanation.  Will try this as soon as i come home from work !